# Array de arrays eliminar elementos duplicados y formar uno nuevo

Tags: javascript, html, array

Tengo una inquietud que no puedo resolver. Ahi vamos: Tengo un array de este estilo :

```
 array = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
[2,5,7,1,63,23,1,41,3,1,51,3,12,9,0],
[2,3,4,6,1,2,3,53,43,41,41,51,3,4,34,6544]
]
```

Necesito generar un nuevo array con los valores que NO se repitan, por ejemplo que quede algo asi:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,34,41,51,53,etc]
```

Que método podría usar? Desde ya mil gracias.

Comment: Primero usa la función `flat()` para convertir los 3 arreglos en uno solo. Luego crea un `Set` pasándole como parámetro el arreglo anterior, el `Set` quitará los elementos duplicados. Luego convierte el `Set` en un arreglo.

Comment: @Lobos considera agregar tu comentario como una respuesta, ya que es una muy buena solución la que propones.

Answer (score 5):

Tal como dice @Lobos, se puede usar `.flat` y `Set`:

```js
const  array = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
[2,5,7,1,63,23,1,41,3,1,51,3,12,9,0],
[2,3,4,6,1,2,3,53,43,41,41,51,3,4,34,6544]
];


const res = [...new Set(array.flat())];

console.log(res);
```

`.flat()` puede recibir un argumento (por defecto es 1) que indica la profundidad que va a "aplanar", si tuviésemos *n* arreglos anidados, indicamos `.flat(n)`, el argumento también puede tomar el valor `Infinity`.

`Set` esta diseñado específicamente para almacenar valores únicos, en general se utiliza para almacenar valores primitivos únicos. Los valores que estén repetidos que se intenten almacenar no van a insertarse y tampoco se lanzará una excepción en dicho proceso. El constructor puede recibir un objeto iterable, como `Array` o `Map`.
Siempre que nos enfrentemos a el problema de obtener valores únicos, tenemos que considerar `Set`. Hay que tener en cuenta que en el caso que busquemos objetos únicos, `Set` buscará las referencias únicas, no los valores que componen el objeto.

Comment: Con este metodo lo pude resolver, muchas gracias!